# Biconditionals and Conjunctions in Truth Tables

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, logic

Given that a biconditional $p\iff q$ is True what can be concluded from the statement $\lnot p\land \lnot q$?

In a worded example:

I wear my running shoes if and only if I exercise. (True)

I am not exercising AND I am not wearing my running shoes. (?)

If we set up a truth table, the biconditional is True in two of the four occurrences, but we see that $\lnot p\land \lnot q$ is both True and False, which would mean there is no conclusion, correct?

Comment: The wording seems to me that you are not being what you can conclude *about* $\lnot p\land\lnot q$ *from* $p\leftrightarrow q$ .  Rather it seems you are being asked *about what* you can conclude *from* $p\leftrightarrow q$ and $\lnot p\land\lnot q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $p\iff q$ means that $p$ and $q$ have identical truth values, which
   means that $\lnot p$ and $\lnot q$ have identical truth values,
   which means that $\lnot p \land \lnot q$ is a conjunction of
   propositions with identical truth vaulues (i.e., both true or both
   false).
2. $\lnot p \land \lnot q$ is, by definition, true precisely when both
   conjuncts are true.

So, $(2)$ entails that both $p$ and $q$ are false.

And, $(1)$ neither entails that $(2)$ is true nor that $(2)$ is false.

Comment: In other words, no real meaning.

Comment: Sorry I wrote the wrong thing.

It's very hard multitasking.

Comment: @AaaLol_dude I'd say "undetermined truth value" rather than "no meaning".

Answer (score 1):

Restating Ryan G's answer, which I completely agree with:

Given $P \iff Q$ you know that there are only two possibilities:

Possibility (1) : $P \wedge Q$.

Possibility (2) : $(\neg P) \wedge (\neg Q).$

Since the only information available is that the  biconditional is true, there is no way of determining which of Possibility (1) or Possibility (2) pertains.